# How can I rethrow an exception from catch block in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exception

Should I approach the exception handling in the same manner as .NET?

Then, how can I re-throw an exception from catch block in PowerShell?

Is `throw` is enough? Or would `throw $_` be better?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If you would like to *re-throw* original exception you could use `throw` (most common), or `throw $_`, or `throw $_.Exception`

ps: inside `catch` variable `$_` is not exception by itself, but `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` that contains Exception

---

### Note

The `throw` keyword at PowerShell behaves differently then .NET implementation: in .NET you can only throw `System.Exceptions` itself or its successors, but in PowerShell, you can throw anything and that is automatically wrapped up into a `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException`. See snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/4258647).

Comment: Note: In C#, the `throw` form keeps the original exception's context (source location), but unfortunately this does not appear to be the case in PowerShell.

Comment: It looks like it does nowadays!

Comment: Oh wow. I wonder when they changed it. It definitely didn't in 2017, when I had this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162493

Comment: @D.R. - any clue when they fixed it, or link to an issue about it that got resolved. Just curious, I'm looking a bit myself but haven't found it yet.